# JSON converted to string not adding to Listview

Tags: android, json, listview

I am retrieving data from my server and it is in a JSON ARRAY, when first retrieved it shows in the listview in JSON,  but when I convert it to a string and add it to my listview again it does not show, but when I show it in a TOAST it works.

What could I be doing wrong?

This is my Activity:

```
   private void showLIST(JSONArray jsonArray) {
    JSONObject obj = null;

    //RETRIEVES ALL THE DATA FROM THE SERVER
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        try {
            obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            orderID.add(obj.getString(ORDERID));
            orderUserNumber.add(obj.getString(ORDERUSERNUMBER));
            orderName.add(obj.getString(ORDERNAME));
            orderDateTime.add(obj.getString(ORDERDATETIME));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    //THIS CONVERTS THE JSON TO STRING AND DISPLAYS IT IN A TOAST 
        try {
            name = obj.getString(ORDERNAME);
            JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(name);
            for (int x = 0; x < jsonarray.length(); x++) {
                JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(x);
                names = jsonobject.getString("name");

             //   orderName.add(obj.getString(names));
                Toast.makeText(viewOrdersPage.this, names, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    viewOrderAdapter listOrderAdapter = new viewOrderAdapter(this,orderID, orderUserNumber, orderName, orderDateTime);
    listView.setAdapter(listOrderAdapter);
}
```

My Adapter Code:

```
  private Context context;

private ArrayList<String> orderID;
private ArrayList<String> orderUserNumber;
private ArrayList<String> orderName;
private ArrayList<String> orderDateTime;

public viewOrderAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> orderID, ArrayList<String> orderUserNumber, ArrayList<String> orderName, ArrayList<String> orderDateTime){
    this.context = context;
    this.orderID = orderID;
    this.orderUserNumber = orderUserNumber;
    this.orderName = orderName;
    this.orderDateTime = orderDateTime;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return orderID.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return orderID.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final View listView;
    final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    listView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_orders_item, null);

    TextView id = (TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.orderID);
    TextView number = (TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.orderUserNumber);
    TextView name = (TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.orderName);
    TextView dateTime = (TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.orderDateTime);


    id.setText(orderID.get(position));
    number.setText(orderUserNumber.get(position));
    name.setText(orderName.get(position));
    dateTime.setText(orderDateTime.get(position));

    return listView;
}
```

This is my JSON RESPONSE:

```
[{"orderID":"PQ6B1MlsSMnl6IrxlN7pgkHEQock6G"
,"userNumber":"+639161693630"
,"orderName":"[{\"name\":\"RED HORSE\",\"size\":\"500ML\",\"quantity\":\"4 
BOTTLE\"}]","orderDateTime":"02\/06\/2017, 04:28 am"}
```

This is my logcat when it does not show the converted JSON in the Listview:

```
   W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for RED HORSE
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:550)
W/System.err:     at com.example.gin.orderingcompiledv1.viewOrdersPage.showLIST(viewOrdersPage.java:208)
W/System.err:     at com.example.gin.orderingcompiledv1.viewOrdersPage.access$300(viewOrdersPage.java:46)
W/System.err:     at com.example.gin.orderingcompiledv1.viewOrdersPage$2.onResponse(viewOrdersPage.java:136)
W/System.err:     at com.example.gin.orderingcompiledv1.viewOrdersPage$2.onResponse(viewOrdersPage.java:133)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:65)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6918)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Thanks in advance for any help! :D

Comment: Add the code for adapter as well!

Comment: add your adapter code

Comment: @Imdad Added the adapter code, though the JSON shows in the listview when retrieved but not when coverted :D

Comment: @jaikhambhayta Added the adapter code, though the JSON shows in the listview when retrieved but not when coverted :D

Comment: @Imdad it did nothing sir, well sir my problem is that when I get the data from the server it shows in the listview as JSON, then when I convert the JSON to string and then try to put it into the listview again it does not show.

Comment: are you able to check the size of your all aray ??

Comment: and tell me what size you get

Comment: post your json response

Comment: @GionneLapuz please paste your JSON response ,It will help to understand

Comment: @jaikhambhayta sorry sir, I have added it :D

Comment: run this code and check the logget with your name paste the response

Comment: @jaikhambhayta Sir I found the problem, I am such a f"!$ing idiot hahah. I just changed this **orderName.add(obj.getString(names));** to this **orderName.add(names);** and it worked hahahah Sorry sir for the trouble

Comment: @jaikhambhayta Anyways sir thank you for all the help, I really appreciate it! You deserve an upvote for all the help1

Comment: your welcome..@Gionne Lapuz

Comment: @jaikhambhayta Sir would be okay for me to edit your answer to what made my code work and I will accept it :D Is it okay?

Comment: yes.......its ok

Comment: you can approve the answer if it helpfull for you..thank you

Comment: org.json.JSONException: No value for RED HORSE <--- your problem is here, you are trying to get a value in json object which is hold by this key but it was not exiting